# mvc .net no funciona la vista

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

cuando voy a entrar en el menu audiologeo de mi aplicacion de .net me sale el siguiente error:

Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[serviexpress.auditoria]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'serviexpress.audiologeo'.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[serviexpress.auditoria]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'serviexpress.audiologeo'.

Error de código fuente:

Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Seguimiento de la pila:

[InvalidOperationException: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[serviexpress.auditoria]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'serviexpress.audiologeo'.]

este el controlador de audiologeo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using serviexpress.Models;

namespace serviexpress.Controllers
{
public class AudiologeoController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Audiologeo/
    serviexpressEntities2 bdmensajeria = new serviexpressEntities2();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(bdmensajeria.auditoria.ToList());
    }

    }
   }
```

este es el controlador de login:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Mail;
using serviexpress.Models;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Net;


namespace serviexpress.Controllers
{
public class LoginController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /Login/
serviexpressEntities2 bdmensajeria = new serviexpressEntities2();

public ActionResult Login()
{
return View();
}

// POST: /Login/

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login( login UserLog)
{
using (serviexpressEntities2 bdmensajeria = new serviexpressEntities2())
{
var i = (from p in bdmensajeria.usuario
where p.login.Equals(UserLog.usu) && p.contraseña.Equals(UserLog.clave)
select p).FirstOrDefault();
if (i != null)
{
Session["security"] = true;
Session["nombre"] = i.login;
Session["rol"] = i.id_rol;
Session["ingreso"] = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
Session["url"] = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
else {
ModelState.AddModelError("", "usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
return View();
}
if(Session["rol"].Equals(1)){
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Domicilio");

}
else {
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Contactos");
}

}

}

public ActionResult Logout()
{


audiologeo auditor1 = new audiologeo();
auditor1.login = Session["nombre"].ToString();
DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["ingreso"]);
auditor1.fecha_ingreso = fecha;
auditor1.fecha_salida = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
auditor1.url = Session["url"].ToString();
bdmensajeria.AddToaudiologeo(auditor1);
bdmensajeria.SaveChanges();
Session.Clear();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

// GET: /Registro/

public ActionResult Registro()
{
return View();
}


// POST: /Registro/

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registro(usuario NewUser)
{
try
{
// TODO: Add insert logic here
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
bdmensajeria.AddTousuario(NewUser);
bdmensajeria.SaveChanges();
}
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
catch
{
return View();
}
}


}
}
```

esta es la vista de audiologeo:

>" %>

Index

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            numero
        </th>
        <th>
            login
        </th>
        <th>
            fecha_ingreso
        </th>
        <th>
            fecha_salida
        </th>
        <th>
            url
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.numero }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.numero })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.numero })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.numero %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.login %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.fecha_ingreso) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.fecha_salida) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.url %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas enviando un modelo de tipo `List<serviexpress.auditoria>` pero en la vista estas esperando un modelo de tipo `servexpress.audiologeo`. Nota que en el modelo de la vista estas esperando una instancia que no es una lista, sino un objeto. Tienes que convertir los datos que retornas a la vista al tipo  `servexpress.audiologeo` para que te funcione.

Comment: donde se define el modelo de tipo List<serviexpress.auditoria> en el codigo que subi, como convierto los datos  a la vista al tipo servexpress.audiologeo?

Comment: Donde te lanza el error, es en la vista Index?

Comment: si, es en la vista index de audiologeo.

Comment: Intentare explicarlo de una manera simple: Si en tu vista requieres del modelo `serverexpress.audiologeo`, tienes que asegurarte de enviarle un objeto de ese tipo. Ahora bien, como puedes converitr un objeto `List<serviexpress.auditoria>` a `auditologueo`? Creando una instancia de audiologueo, asignarle los valores que necesita y enviandole esa instancia a la vista.

Answer (score 0):

En tu vista debes la primera línea debe especificar el tipo del modelo. En tu caso sería algo así

```
@model IEnumerable<serviexpress.auditoria>
<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            numero
        </th>
        <th>
            login
        </th>
        <th>
            fecha_ingreso
        </th>
        <th>
            fecha_salida
        </th>
        <th>
            url
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.numero }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.numero })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.numero })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.numero %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.login %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.fecha_ingreso) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.fecha_salida) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.url %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
```